# API Rest só retorna o último valor

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, rest

Estou usando ASP.Net para criar uma API REST

Estou tentando criar um método que retorne uma lista de grupos estruturado dessa forma:

```js
{
  "IdGroup": "1",
  "NameGroup": "Group1",
  "Installations": [
    {
      "IdInstallation": "1",
      "NameInstallation": "Installation 1"
    },
    {
      "IdInstallation": "2",
      "NameInstallation": "Installation 2"
    },
    {
      "IdInstallation": "3",
      "NameInstallation": "Installation 3"
    },
    {
      "IdInstallation": "4",
      "NameInstallation": "Installation 4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Porém meu método está retornândo somente a ultima instalação do grupo **(a instalação 4, neste caso)**.

Meu método:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route ("groups")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetGroups() 
{
    try
    {
        List<Groups> listGroups = new List<Groups>();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "select Groups.IdGroup, Groups.NameGroup, AttributeCloned.IdInstallation, AttributeCloned.NameInstallation " +
                                      "from Groups " +
                                      "join AttributeCloned " +
                                      "on Groups.IdGroup = AttributeCloned.IdGroup "+
                                      "where Groups.IdGroup = 1 "+
                                      "order by IdInstallation asc";

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                Groups group = new Groups();
                Installations inst = new Installations();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    group.IdGroup = reader["IdGroup"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader["IdGroup"]);
                    group.NameGroup = reader["NameGroup"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : reader["NameGroup"].ToString();
                    inst.IdInstallation = reader["IdInstallation"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(reader["IdInstallation"]);
                    inst.NameInstallation = reader["NameInstallation"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : reader["NameInstallation"].ToString();
                }

                group.installations.Add(inst);
                listGroups.Add(group);
            }
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, listGroups.ToArray());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

O que estou errando para que não seja retornado todas as instalações do respectivo grupo?

Comment: Não relacionado à pergunta, mas não deveria ser usado o método `GET`, no lugar de `POST`?

Comment: Adicionei a resposta com o que acredito que seja o problema, mas fiquei curioso para saber porque vc não procura usar um `ORM`.

Comment: Adicione à pergunta o DDL e DML da sua base, para que seja possível reproduzir o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só há um objeto `inst` no seu código e a cada iteração ele é atualizado. Coloque as linhas `Installations inst = new Installations();` e `group.installations.Add(inst);` dentro do while e o problema deverá ser resolvido.

Entretanto, ainda há outro problema, este código só está preparado para retornar uma lista de `groups` com somente uma entrada (no caso é a de id =1). O problema está tanto na query quanto no binding para o seu modelo.

Comment: Ola, Fiz o que você sugeriu, colocar as linhas "Installations inst = new Installations()" e "group.instalations.add(inst)" porém ainda continua retornando somente um elemento em instalações.

Comment: Adicione então à pergunta o DDL e DML da sua base, para que seja possível reproduzir o problema.